Gitlab GraphQL list all branches
How can I list all (or filtered by fields) branches using gitlab GraphQL api?
I can list branches names
{
  project(fullPath: "my/project") {
    repository{
      branchNames(searchPattern: "*", offset: 0, limit: 100)
    }
  }
}

But I need get other fields (merged, protected, etc.) and/or filter by that fields

Don't their documentation explain that?

Their documentation only has a way to get a list of branch names

So, that's it...

Branch names and branches advanced fields are not the same.
The API gives us more advanced information: name, commit, merged, protected, developers_can_push, developers_can_merge, can_push, default, web_url

So there is a documentation about branches advanced fields?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html
